# Blazor Server: NavigationManager in Middleware

Tags: c#, blazor, middleware, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to create a httphandler in a Blazor Server app that handles all unsuccessful status codes. If a 401 is thrown, I want to redirect to a custom 401 page.

For some reason, I cannot get the NavigationManager to work after depency injection. It looks like it does load the NavigationManager, but it never initializes it.

```
public class RichardsHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected readonly NavigationManager _navManager;
    public RichardsHandler(NavigationManager navigationManager)
    {
        _navManager = navigationManager;
    }
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        _navManager.NavigateTo("/401");

        return response;
    }
}
```

I simply put the NavigateTo there to try and navigate to another page, but I always get a "InvalidOperationException: 'RemoteNavigationManager' has not been initialized" exception.

Again, this is a Blazor Serverside app. Am I overlooking something or is this by design in the NavigationManager?

Comment: When you say "handles all unsuccessful status codes" is that at initial startup or during routing in the application?  Is that the Blazor `NavigationManager` you are trying to use?

Comment: It's during routing. Let's say I go to a forbidden page, then I expect a 403 returning. It's after I make a call to an api. Yes it's the Blazor one.

Comment: I don't think you can use `NavigationManager` outside Blazor components.  In this case, I believe you need to change the Uri of the request.

Comment: this makes little sense as middleware in Blazor server - it would only run for the initial page load, not for subsequent navigation. There is a Router component that handles unauthorised routing - maybe that is where you want to be looking?

Comment: That sounds good, thanks for that suggestion. I had a feeling I might be putting this in the wrong place. I've only been working in Blazor for a couple of months, I'll check out that Router component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware will only be called on the initial load of the Application.  After that everything is handled in-page by the various bits of code that make up the navigation manager pipeline and by router component: there are no calls back to the server and therefore no middleware invoked.

`NavigationManager` is a DI service that receives data from the Blazor client side code running in the browser whenever a browser side navigation event occurs.  You can't access it directly from middleware because it only exists in the Blazor Hub session on the server.

If you want to show a specific component or markup on page not found and unauthorized requests, code it into `App.razor`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will concentrate on the App.razor first now.