# Blazor - NavigationManager not initialized error

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor server-side application, I have created a class to return the baseURI that is being used by the user as a string. But every time I test and debug by code, I get the same error every time:

> InvalidOperationException: 'RemoteNavigationManager' has not been initialized.

My limited understanding was that DI through the constructor was the way to go, as this is a class and not a component, but I must be missing something else as well (maybe syntax?) since my code keeps breaking.

My class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Tester.Data
{
    public class GetNav
    {
        private NavigationManager _navigationManager { get; }

        public GetNav(NavigationManager navigationManager)
        {
            _navigationManager = navigationManager;
        }

        public async Task<String> GetNavLink()
        {
            var nav = _navigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(_navigationManager.BaseUri).ToString();
            if (nav != null)
            {
                return nav;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added full stack-trace:

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. See the inner exception for more information. To show additional information call 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'.)
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Projects\App\Tester\Program.cs:line 33

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager.AssertInitialized()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager.BaseUri.get()
    Tester.Data.GetNav.GetNavLink() in GetNav.cs

Inner Exception 1:
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ('RemoteNavigationManager' has not been initialized.)

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: 'RemoteNavigationManager' has not been initialized.
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: @mxmissile I have copied the full error that appeared while debugging. Let me know if that doesn't help.

Comment: The issue is not how you are injecting `NavigationManager` but IF `NavigationManager` is available to be injected.  You need a .razor component and this SO answer has a great explanation (also from MrC :-) ) https://stackoverflow.com/a/72048125/886945 and MrC's answer below should help.

Comment: @SteveWong Unfortunately, I need the navurl in order to create a connection string before the app itself is built, so I'm not sure if that would work...

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't do it that way.

Here's a different approach.

A service class to hold the data.

```cs
public class AppInfo
{
    public string? AppUrl { get; private set; }

    public void UpdateAppUrl(string url)
    {
        this.AppUrl = url;
    }
}
```

Registered in DI.  I've made this scoped as you're site could have multiple Urls.

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<AppInfo>();
```

And a component

```cs
public class AppInfoProvider : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] private NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; } = default!;
    [Inject] private AppInfo AppInfo { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => this.AppInfo.UpdateAppUrl(this.NavigationManager.BaseUri);
}
```

To `App`. It gets rendered and populates the service when a new SPA session starts.

```cs
<AppInfoProvider />
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

And finally `Index` to demo the result:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject AppInfo AppInfo 
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="alert alert-info">@AppInfo.AppUrl</div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution; however, I wonder if it will still work for my needs. I need the navigation manager to get the baseURI in order to create a connection string prior to actually building the app. Can this still work?